# Broken Gravatar images in comments

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I have no idea why, but recently, all new comments on my WordPress site have broken avatar image links. Here is a page that shows the issue: http://joshnh.com/2012/10/12/how-does-line-height-actually-work/#comments

Any idea why this is happening? I haven't installed any plugins recently, so why has it started playing up all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that the default path for the fallback image wasn't being set. I have fixed that (in functions.php) and it is working correctly!

Thanks to @markratledge for leading me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Developer Tools show a "bad request" error, so switch to the twentyeleven theme to be sure it's not a theme issue. And disable the W3TC plugin and see if anything changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately neither of them fixed the problem.